# How to count the particular values in the field in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a simple table in Google Data Studio, which fetches data from MySql table. For example, 
"Peter
John
Mike
Peter
George
Peter"

The above are the set of values in a field,
Here I have to count the number of "Peter" in the field and display the count. 
Is it possible to display the count of particular values from a single field? If so, what function should I apply to get the required output?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `REGEXP_MATCH` function to create a new field. Try this:

1. Create new field called `Peter Count` and use this formula:

   ```
   CASE
     WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(FIELD_NAME, "Peter") THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END
   ```
2. Make sure the new field has a field type of `Number` and aggregation of `SUM`
3. Create a scorecard in your report and select your new field as the metric.

That should add up the occurrences of Peter and ignore other names.